# Ref between chapter

Tags: cross-referencing

Is it possible to use `\ref` for something (table) in chapter `kap03` that is included in `kap02` in some way? Thank you

I have a file in which are loaded other `.tex` files.

```
\include{kap02}
\include{kap03}
\include{kap04}
```

Comment: If there is a \label{foo} in `kap02` you can say `\ref{foo}` in any other of the files as well, since you're using `\include` (or `\input`). If you're using cross-references from other, already compiled documents, you need the `xr` - package, for example

Comment: Yes, of course. Give the table in `kap02` a label, say `\caption{...}\label{tab:first}`, and reference it in `kap03` e.g. with `\ref{tab:first}`.